# When I create views from Clearcase explorer, both development and the integration views get created as snapshot

Tags: dynamic, view, clearcase, explorer, snapshot

I do not get the option at all to choose for the views to be snapshot or dynamic.
What I would want is the development view to be snapshot and the integration view to be dynamic. Why is it that I am not prompted to let me choose my views to be snapshot/dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

May be you have [ClearCase LT](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearcase/cclt/), which only provides snapshot view ?

As mentioned in the [ClearCase mkview help page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm):

> Specifying the kind of view
>
> **Default**
>
> - ClearCase: Dynamic view.
> - ClearCase LT: Snapshot view

Anyway, you can try to create your views through command line `cleartool`:

- Snapshot:

  ```
    cleartool mkview -snap -tag yourView_snap -stream yourStream@\yourPVob -stg aStorage aViewPath
  ```
- Dynamic:

  ```
    cleartool mkview -tag yourView -stream yourStream@\yourPVob -stg aStorage
  ```

Please note the naming convention (yourView_snap for snapshot view): this *is* a convention, and it should reflect:

- your login
- the name of the stream

More details in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395388/how-to-create-clearcase-views-automatically/395498#395498).

---

Also note that an "integration view" is not always made for a "dynamic view": if you make some "integration test" involving some compilation, a snapshot view may be more adapted.