# Get copy of files from ClearCase

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, clearcase

We're just moving from VSS to ClearCase and it's nearly impossible to find out how to do anything :-(
I need to script (using ClearTool?) a sort of VSS-GetLatest, i.e copy a folder and all its contents to a windows folder

Any clues (in short words please as I'm new to this!)

Comment: By any chance, is your need to copy a folder and all of it's contents to a windows folder because you need to see / edit the files disconnected from clearcase?  If so, I think this may be the wrong source code control tool for you.  Has your team considered a tool that doesn't require a persistent connection to the repository (cvs,svn,git, etc.)?

Comment: @DaveParillo: a snapshot view can allow the consultation of data without persistent connection, once the initial update is done, like any CVS or SVN workspace checkout. Git, on the other hand, is a DVCS, and has the full repository on the local workstation. Completelty different.

Comment: @Pete: do not hesitate to leave further question as comments on my answer: that way I will be notified of those comments, and will be able to address them.

Comment: Also see: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/sourcesafemigrationtorationalclearcase/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the most important labels from VSS and import them inside ClearCase. You can use 'clearfsimport' utility, it's like a script.

Answer (score 1):

- If you have your data in a VOB, what you need to access the LATEST of the branch '`main`', you need to define a view.
  I recommend a dynamic view to begin with, for a quick browse of the data.
  See [this question for creating views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660049/when-i-create-views-from-clearcase-explorer-both-development-and-the-integration/660209#660209).
- if you still have to import data into your VOBS, clearfsimport is a good option.
  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively#144310) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293682/clearfsimport-utility-without-rmname-option/1293707#1293707).

Comment: Cheers for you help. I am using a Dynamic view and it all seems to work ok