# how to remove a version in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I want to check out a directory , let's say `/vobs/myvob/src/` to add a new file in this directory. But by mistake rather than checked out `/vobs/myvob/src` I checked out `/vobs/myvob/scr/` and even worse checked in it. Then directory `scr` has a new version :  `scr@mybranch/1`  (let's say I'm working on branch `mybranch`)

After realized that I've made a mistake, I remove the newly created version by:

```
ct rmver scr@myranch/1
```

then use `ct ls parent_dir_of_scr` to do the double check  and I found although `scr@mybranch/1` disappeared, `scr@mybranch/0` is still there .
Not 100% sure but I'm afraid I should not try to remove that version in the same way , cus it might let clearcase remove a version in main as well.
So my question is how should I do a totally "clean up" in this situation .

Need your help . thanks in advance .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, as mentioned in [How do I roll back a file checked in to Clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147055/how-do-i-roll-back-a-file-checked-in-to-clearcase), the one command to never ever do is `rmver`.
Even if in your case it could be appropriate, this is simply too dangerous, for it removes the version and all its associated metadata (hyperlinks, labels and so on).

Then, you mention:

> rather than checked out `/vobs/myvob/src` I checked out `/vobs/myvob/scr/`...

... well `/vobs/myvob/src` is quite similar to `/vobs/myvob/src` here. I do not see any differences between the "two" directories.

If you want to add a file to a directory through the CLI cleartool, you will need to:

- checkout `/vobs/myvob/src` (parent directory)
- `mkelem` the file to add
- checkin the parent directory

Finally, the "version 0" you see is only a "declarative" version to act as a starting point for branches.
That is why the other answers suggest you to `rmbranch` (remove the branch) for that element. It only serves the purpose of cleaning the  lsvtree (version tree).

```
"cleartool rmbranch -force $element"
```

as mentioned in the [ten best scripts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/03July/getstart/CC/10triggers.pdf).

Comment: @Jerry Starts with a version tree done from the ClearCase Explorer. That will give you all the versions of a given element.

Comment: Thanks. But I can only have access to CLI.

Comment: @Jerry Then `cleartool lsvtree aFile` is the CLI way to see the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you remove version 1 of a file on your branch, your branch will remain (with version 0). If you really want to do a clean-up you can remove the branch ([ct rmbranch](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0530&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/u_man/cat1/ct%2Brmbranch.z) your_branch) for the file -- it won't remove the version from mainline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely remove a version of an object (file or directory) from Clearcase control, I suggest you to use the following command:

```
cleartool rmver –xbranch –xlabel –xattr –xhlink test.txt@@\main\3
```

Command options are described on [this snip2code post](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11571/How-to-force-remove-an-element-in-Clearc?fromPage=1).