# Script to prepare scenarios to test findmerge command

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I'm testing a clearcase merge script and I'd like to be able to have another script that could produce these 2 test scenarios every time it runs:

1. Modify 3 files for a trivial merge (100% automatic, no diff needed)
2. Modify 3 files for a conflicting merge, user resolution required

What I'd like to know are the steps/clearcase commands needed to prepare these files. All must be done through command-line (using cleartool commands). I already have a dynamic view and some test files I can use. Probably I'll need to create a destination test branch too.

The merge is done using the `ct findmerge` command like this:

```
`cleartool findmerge filepath -fver version  -merge -log NUL -c comment`
```

I need to validate the output in each of the cases, to include them in a report and also ensure that no user interaction is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

- to have two branches where you makes your parallel evolutions in your files
- to use simply `cleartool checkout -nc myFile ; echo new modif >> myFile ; cleartool checkin -nc myFile` for adding evolution with a trivial merge in one branch (leave the same file untouched in the other branch)
- to use the same process in both branches with a different echo each time in order to add a new line different in both version of `myFile`: that will result in non-trivial merge.

Don't forget that you can also have trivial/non-trivial merges on the **directory** level (when files are added/removed): a non-trivial one would be in case of an **[evil-twin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927206/cleartool-question/2927385#2927385)**.

Comment: great, thank you! Now, my next question would be how to change from one branch to the other before I execute these 3 commands you wrote.

Comment: @epzee: I would recommend a simple solution: using two different dynamic views, each one with a config spec set on the right branch. Use one of those view as the destination for your merge, where you will execute your findmerge.