# How can I view only a set of files in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I need to create a tar of only a set of files (`a.c`, `b.c`, `c.c`) obtained from the ClearCase repository.
I need all latest versions of those files, and I am writing a script to do this.

How can I do it?
Should I create a new static view with a modified config spec and then do a tar?
If so, how can I select only those files to appear in the view and not the entire code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a snapshot view with a config spec like:

```
element * /main/LATEST
load /vob/path/to/a.c
load /vob/path/to/b.c
load /vob/path/to/c.c
```

(I am assuming here base ClearCase, not UCM ClearCase)

That would only load the relevant files, with the LATEST version selected.

You can script the creation of a snapshot view (to do only once) with the `cleartool mkview` command.
See examples [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/660209/6309).

See also "[What are the differences between a snapshot view and a dynamic view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378)":
if you have a dynamic view with a simple config spec:

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

Then you wouldn't need to *load* files, only to mount the vob: all the files would be available.
That can be a solution too.