# Replacement of cleartool setview exec

Tags: clearcase

For some reason, our company don't support clearcase anymore.So I need to remove it from scripts,use folder to replace it.
For the command

```
Cleartool setview -exec "$RUN_SCRIPT paramter1 paramter2" $MY_CC_VIEW
$RUN_SCRIPT=/vobs/sw/ecomps/tools/script_remote.sh (a script located in view path)
```

how to replace it?
cd a path that script located in ,then execute the command?

```
cd $MY_CC_VIEW_PATH/vobs/sw/ecomps && tools/script_remote.sh paramter1 paramter2
```

Answer (score 0):

[`cleartool setview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) is for setting the view content of dynamic views, so if ClearCase is not running anymore, you would not be able to access any dynamic view anyway.

As I mentioned in "[Python and ClearCase `setview`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)", never use setview in a script anyway: always use the full `/view/viewTag/vobs/aVobTag/...` path.

But again, if ClearCase is stopped, that dynamic view path would not be accessible: you should at least checkout [snapshot views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/660209/6309), whose content would remain accessible even if there is no ClearCase server running.

Comment: thanks @VonC .I have checkout the view content.Now the $MY_CC_VIEW_PATH/vobs/sw/ecomps is a common directory on linux,just has the same path as clear view. If it's ok to cd the path then execute command.does it has the same function as setview -exec?

Comment: If it is a snapshot view path, you won't need setview

Comment: @clara If it is a dynamic view, using `/view/<aview>/vobs/<avob>` would be the same as `setview`, except it won't have the inconveniences of `setview` I described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309.

Comment: I am still working on the debug of GNU make,not sure whether it works.