# Eclipse CDT Not updating new files or directories

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I have a large project that is in a collection on directories and built externally to eclipse. We are using clearcase as SCM so it basically mounts the code changes for each view to a directory.

This has been working well for some time and just using Eclipse to traverse and edit code has been great.

To edit, In Eclipse, I create a new c++ project and then import all the directories of the codebase in as "File System" option

in the import popup, I select Advanced>> and select "Create links in workspace", selecting both options below; Create virtual folders and create link locations relative to PROJECT_LOC

This seems to allow me to edit the source files in their place in the mounted directory. However, I noticed that if I add a new file or directory, or a new one gets added in the view, they do not appear in eclipse until I re import the directory.

Answer (score 1):

"[Creating linked resources](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm)" is indeed the recommended best practice to reference a "[linked folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470833/6309)" that I mentioned in 2009.

But I always found working better with ClearCase **[snapshot views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/660209/6309)** than dynamic views (the latter  are ill-suited for many read-write operation involved with reading/compiling sources)

Answer (score 0):

Importing the directories is possibly not the cause of this issue, but it's solved by creating my project differently.

Selecting File >> New >> Folder >> Advanced >> Link To altrenate location, seems to work far better than the importing way I was doing things and in this case it does refresh files and seems to work much faster to boot.